# How to animate a radial engine?

Tags: animation, parent

I have already asked a question based on this topic today which was well answered. It is related to my new question so I put the link 
[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61348/parented-object-follow-different-path)!

First I will post a picture for clarity.

[image: a busy cat]

My aim is that the red "ball" is moving on the path with the red flashes (it's a bezier circle), additionally it should not rotate on its own axes.
The Blue, Green, Yellow, and other "balls" should follow the Red one and also move the pistons with the same color towards and away of the center of the whole construction.

I tried the solution which was suggested in the last question I asked and it worked well, but with these new "conrod endings/crankshafts" it doesn't  work anymore. I have also tried to make the red ball follow the red line via "Follow Path" constraint but then the method of "Copy Location" for the pistons it doesn't work anymore.

I'm very sorry for such a specific question. Maybe I should just build a V engine ... but then again I guess I would have the same problem with the crankshaft.